# r apply multiple conditions to multiple columns (vectors of function argument values)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to apply multiple conditions to multiple columns of a data.frame where condition i should be applied to column i, i.e. the applied condition is dependent on the column I am in. I have a working solution but it has two major drawbacks, it's potentially slow on large data as it uses a for loop and it requires the two input vectors "columns the condition is applied to" and "condition to be applied" in the same order. I envisaged a solution that utilizes fast data wrangling package functions e.g. dplyr, data.table and is more flexible with respect to order of argument vector elements. an example should make it clear (here the condition is only a threshold test but in the bigger problem it may be a more complex boolean expression involving variables of the data set).

```
t <- structure(list(a = c(2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L), 
                    b = c(5L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 20L), 
                    c = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), 
               .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), 
               class = "data.frame", 
               row.names = c(NA, -5L))

foo_threshold <- 
  function(data, cols, thresholds, condition_name){
    df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(cols), nrow = nrow(data)))
    colnames(df) <- paste0(cols, "_", condition_name)

    for (i in 1:length(cols)){
      df[,i] <- ifelse(data[,i] > thresholds[i],T,F)
      }
    return(df)
    }

foo_threshold(data = t, cols = c("a", "b"), thresholds = c(5, 18), 
              condition_name = "bigger_threshold")
```

I have tried to solve it in a dplyr chain but I fail to pass the argument vectors correctly, i.e. how to make it clear that he should apply condition i to column i. below an illustration where I was going. it's not working and it misses some points but I think it illustrates what I am trying to achieve. note that here conditions are assumed to be in a data.frame where column variable holds the col names and threshold is extracted via a lookup (dplyr filer + select chain).

```
foo_threshold <- function(data, cols, thresholds, cond_name) {
  require(dplyr)
  # fun to evaluate boolean condition
  foo <- function(x) {
    threshold <- thresholds %>% filter(variable==x) %>% select(threshold)
    temp <- ifelse(x > threshold, T, F)
    return(temp)
    }

  vars <- setNames(cols, paste0(cols,"_",cond_name))

  df_out <-
    data %>%
    select_(.dots = cols) %>%
    mutate_(funs(foo(.)), vars) %>%
    select_(.dots = names(vars))

  return(df_out)
  }

# create threshold table
temp <- 
  data.frame(variable = c("a", "b"),
             threshold = c(5, 18),
             stringsAsFactors = F)

# call function (doesn't work)
foo_threshold(data = t, thresholds = temp, cond_name = "bigger_threshold")
```

**Edit**: @thepule data.frame of conditions may look like below where x is the column. so each condition is evaluated for each row of its corresponding column.

```
conditions <- 
  data.frame(variable = c("a", "b"),
             condition = c("x > 5 and x < 10", "!x %in% c("o", "p")"),
             stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: I would caution against naming an object `t` as that is the transpose function

Comment: thanks for the hint. it was supposed to stand for temp and I was lazy.

Comment: OK, it is definitely trickier with conditions in that format. Interesting problem though.

Comment: OK, it is definitely trickier with conditions in that format. Interesting problem though. What do "o" and "p" represent there?

Comment: Example was not perfect. Wanted to make clear that boolean does not neef to be applied only to numeric but also character variables. But of course it didn't make sense to compare against numeric and character values at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final attempt at an answer.  Tried to make the code more generic so that it can accept arbitrary functions.  Nicely it also appears to run significantly faster than any of my previous answers. I am also quite tired atm so apologies if I have made a silly mistake.

```
temp <- structure(list(a = c(2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L), 
                       b = c(5L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 20L), 
                       c = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), 
                  .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                  class = "data.frame", 
                  row.names = c(NA, -5L))



condition <- c(function(x)  x> 5  , 
               function(x) x > 18 )


foo_threshold <- function ( data , cols , threshold , condition_name ) {
    dat <- data[0]
    for ( i in 1:length(condition))     dat[cols[i]] <- condition[[i]]( data[[cols[i]]] )
    names(dat) <- paste0( cols , "_" , condition_name)
    return(dat)
}


foo_threshold(data = temp, cols = c("a", "b"), threshold  = condition , 
           condition_name = "bigger_threshold")
```

Comment: in your function definition you refer to temp when it should be data. otherwise I really like the flexibility it gives me regarding vector of conditions and performance seems good.

Comment: I will accept this one for now although I will further think about how to solve the order problem in the vectors of argument values, i.e. it shouldn't have to be same order in cols and threshold. thanks!

Comment: You are right, sorry about the silly mistake, will update !

Comment: If you want them to be order unimportant you can used a named list to link the functions to the variables for example

 funs <- list( a = function(x) x > 5 ,  
      b = function(x) x > 18 )
 
 foo_threshold <- function ( data , threshold , condition_name ){
  dat <- data[0]
  for ( i in  names(threshold)  )  dat[i] <- threshold[[i]]( data[[i]] )
  names(dat) <- paste0( names(threshold) , "_" , condition_name)
  return(dat)
 }
 
 foo_threshold(data = temp, threshold  =  funs , 
      condition_name = "bigger_threshold")

Comment: Good idea! I'll try that tmr.

Answer (score 2):

Made another attempt using sweep instead of mapply. Left the previous answer as it was as I feel it adds value showing how inefficient mapply is.
This new answer appears to run at a little over twice as fast as the OP. I think it is a tiny bit slower than the current best rated answer but has slightly more concise code.

It runs even faster if you are willing to accept the result as a matrix instead of a data.frame.

```
library(dplyr) 


temp <- structure(list(a = c(2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L), 
                    b = c(5L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 20L), 
                    c = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), 
                    .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                    class = "data.frame", 
                    row.names = c(NA, -5L))

foo_threshold <- function(data , cols , thresholds , condition_name ) {
    dat <- sweep ( data [ cols ] , 2  ,  thresholds , ">" ) %>%  as.data.frame()
    names(dat) <- paste0(names(dat) , "_" , condition_name)
    return(dat)
} 

foo_threshold(data = temp, cols = c("a", "b"), thresholds = c(5, 18), 
              condition_name = "bigger_threshold")
```

Comment: I think temp in your function call should be t as in OP initial question or is this on purpose to avoid using t?

Comment: It was indeed to avoid using t, I've updated the answer to make the data source more clear.

Comment: how would answer change if output was matrix?

Comment: It would just run slightly faster as you don't need to do the conversion to data.frame. It is relatively minor though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

 foo_threshold <-
     function(data, cols, thresholds, condition_name){
         temp <- rbind(data[,cols], thresholds) %>%
         lapply(function(x) x[1:length(x)-1] > last(x)) %>% data.frame()
         colnames(temp) <- paste0(cols, "_", condition_name)
         return(temp)

     }

 foo_threshold(data = t, cols = c("a", "b"), thresholds = c(5, 18), 
               condition_name = "bigger_threshold")
```

In order to test which is faster:

```
test <- data.frame(a = runif(10000000), b = runif(10000000), stringsAsFactors = F)

 lapply(list(foo_threshold_original, foo_threshold),
        function(x) system.time(x(data = test, cols = c("a", "b"), thresholds = c(0.5, 0.8), 
                      condition_name = "bigger_threshold")))
```

where foo_threshold_original is your initial version.
The result is:

```
[[1]]
   user  system elapsed 
   3.95    0.64    4.58 

[[2]]
   user  system elapsed 
   1.73    0.24    1.96
```

So the new version is actually faster on bigger data frames.

Comment: as I see it you rowbind the thresholds as last row to the input data and then compare all but last row to last row yielding a Boolean data.frame. I like the idea, although I think you should delete the last row of result data.frame. only problem I have is that the conditions in this example are numeric thresholds but the bigger problem has Boolean expressions that need to be evaluated.

Comment: I see, yeah this would do for numeric thresholds only.

Comment: in addition I would still have to provide cols and thresholds in same order and could not use a data.frame of conditions that are extracted via lookup. but it's definitely an improvement of performance.

Comment: Can you add a more realistic example of threshold? And one of the data frame of conditions you want to use as a lookup table?

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? Doesn't use dplyr (I loaded it anyway to use the pipes though)

```
library(dplyr)

foo_threshold <- function( data , cols , thresholds , condition_name){
    dat <- mapply( function(x , val)  x > val  , data[cols] , thresholds ) %>%  as.data.frame
    names(dat) <- paste0(names(dat) , "_" , condition_name)
    return(dat)
}
```

edit: simplified

Comment: Just ran some speed tests and my code is actually 10x slower than the OPs. So best avoid if you are interested in speed !!

Comment: I thought I could somehow utilize mapply. surprised that it's so much slower.